# Troubleshooting internal links (href="#x" id="x")

Tags: html, css

I wonder if anyone has a genius idea for why my internal links are not working on a webpage.
I've set the html with the standard

```
<a href="#link"><button>Some Text</button></a>
....
bunch of content
....
<div id="link"></div>
```

Here is the codepen link
    http://codepen.io/Cornucopia/pen/vyrPWw?editors=1100#0

This was not working for unknown reasons until I greyed out enough bits of code and isolated the line that caused the problem.  In one of the linked css files was a float:left for the li elements.  The command is not associated with the button link, and so I can't fathom why it would keep the hyperlink from working.  But when the " .grid .tile {float: left;} " is greyed out then the link works again.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/ — You can't put buttons inside links.

Comment: @Quentin, the button/link does work. Check the codepen.io link

Comment: @varlogtim — That doesn't make it valid, and I wouldn't bet on it continuing to work reliably across all the browsers and versions of browsers you haven't tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that everything is floated left except for your `<div id="link"></div>`. I tested the following and it seems to work.

```
.grid .tile { float: left;} /*cuase of problem*/
#link { clear:left;} /* add this */
```

The `clear:left;` breaks the `float` and puts the `div` back into the position it would be in. Then the floats start back up again. :)

One potential issue is that you may not want a break in the pictures. I.e., if you still want everything to line up against each other, the dude pics and the car pics, then just put `#link { float:left; }` but in my opinion since the pictures are of different types the break seems appropriate.

Comment: Varlogtim -you're absolutely right.  This resolved the problem.

Comment: Awesome to hear! The answer by @Deadpool illustrates the reason why it broke very well. I suppose mine was rather short.

Answer (score 2):

the result you getting is absolutely correct.

Case 1:

```
/*.grid .tile {float: left;} */
<div id="link" style="width:100%;height:30px;background:yellow;"></div>
```

Result:

[image]

And, on click of your button you come to this location.

Case 2:

```
.grid .tile {float: left;} 
<div id="link" style="width:100%;height:30px;background:yellow;"></div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

See, the location of div now (yellow background)

So, the anchor is working correctly. There is no issue in browser rendering, html or JavaScript.

**Reason of Mishap in 2nd Case**

You do not completely understand of float. It renders an item like some mixed behavior of (display:inline + Position absolute), which means, first ---> it is ***no longer eligible to take height and then give space to next item***. Second, ***this is no longer going to effect the location of other items in Y-axis, ie, height***.

So now all your li's (which are all float:left) are having no effect on taking space on Y-axis or taking space in height. So Div, has shifted up (like position:absolute items do not effect on other items).

So, removing same you get your desired result.

Hope, this helps!